# Google Maps - open InfoWindow onMouseover instead onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a question regarding Google Maps and a jquery plugin that I use to display maps, etc.

All works fine, Marker Positioning, reload of page (with new db query to retrieve new data based on the new map coordinates, etc. ....)

Only thing that I did not manage to get to work is to change the behavior of the info windows (bubbles) on the map.

I would like them to **open "onMouseOver" instead of "onClick"** - can you help me out?

What I am using is this: http://gmap.nurtext.de/download.html
I know it's not the "most up tp date" thing, but it does what I need (and it's easy).

Sample is here: http://www.divessi.com/code/geo/divecenter.php?lat=48.14&lon=11.73&s=600

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. When looping throught the markers, add this:

```
GEvent.addListener(gmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
   gmarker.openInfoWindowHtml(opts.html_prepend + marker.html + opts.html_append);   
});
```

**mouseover**, or any other GMarker event http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker

EDIT. I notice that you are using the deprecated Google Maps v2. I edited the code. Basically is what you had there. But be sure to add the listener before adding the marker to the overlay, just in case.

EDIT2. To avoid have the same infowindow for all your markers, wrap the code in a function so that a closure is created: (for more info read "The infamous Loop Problem" http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ )

```
function listenMarker (gmarker,marker) {
    GEvent.addListener(gmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
       gmarker.openInfoWindowHtml(opts.html_prepend + marker.html + opts.html_append);   
     });
}
```

Put the function at the end of your file for example and call it inside the loop.

Comment: It ALMOST works ... 

I added your code 
`GEvent.addListener(gmarker, "mouseover", function() {      this.openInfoWindowHtml("test " + j + " - " + opts.html_prepend + marker.html + opts.html_append);
      });`


I changed gmarker.openInfoWindowHtml() to this.openInfoWindowHtml() - now the info Windows appear at the correct markers -. just the HTML content is always the same (of the last set Icon) ... any tipp? 

Source is here: http://www.divessi.com/code/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.1_CK.js (lines 185-190) ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a js file included in the sample you linked to above

```
/code/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0_CK.js
```

There are several lines of code in there related to the mouseover event and they are commented out:

```
//GEvent.addListener(gmarker,"mouseover", function() {
// this.openInfoWindowHtml(myHtml[j]);
//});
```

and

```
//GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {this.openInfoWindowHtml("no." + j + opts.markers[j]);});
//GEvent.addListener(gmarker,"mouseover", function() {
// this.openInfoWindowHtml("test " + j); //+ ": " + opts.html_prepend + marker.html + opts.html_append
//});
```

This is the reference for the Google Maps Javascript API V2 that the plugin is using:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker

You can see definitions of the methods used by the plugin.

I'd recommend having a look at the reference then try uncommenting some of the lines above as you see fit.

Version 3 of the API is quite easy to use in case you wanted to try it without a plugin.

HTH